# Avoiding cycles in directed graph

Tags: prolog

I am writing a simple program in SWI-Prolog to run through a directed graph, from one node to the next. I'm having trouble avoiding cycles though and would like some help. Each edge has a cost associated with it, and each node has a "stay time".

```
edge(a, b, 10).
edge(a, c, 20).
edge(c, d, 50).
edge(c, b, 40).
edge(d, b, 30).
edge(d, a, 40).

stay(a, 10).
stay(c, 30).
stay(b, 15).
stay(d, 20). 

route(Start, End, Route, Cost) :-
  edge(Start, End, Cost),
  append([Start], [End], Route).

route(Start, End, Route, Cost) :-
  edge(Start, Next, FirstCost),
  stay(Next, StayTime),
  route(Next, End, NewRoute, SecondCost),
  Cost is FirstCost + SecondCost + StayTime,
  append([Start], NewRoute, Route).
```

I get the following output in swipl:

```
?- route(a,b,Routing,Cost).
Routing = [a, b],
Cost = 10 ;
Routing = [a, c, b],
Cost = 90 ;
Routing = [a, c, d, b],
Cost = 150 ;
Routing = [a, c, d, a, b],
Cost = 180 ;
Routing = [a, c, d, a, c, b],
Cost = 260 .
```

As you can see, after the 3rd route, the cycles begin to occur. I would like to avoid them, but I'm slightly unsure of how to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some 'tricks of the trade' to make the program working, and more efficient: instead of appending, 'cons' the nodes in a *accumulator*, and also accumulate costs. This requires two more variables, but the resulting procedure is *tail recursive*, and Prolog can apply a basic optimization that make the program complexity linear in space.

```
route(Start, End, PathAcc, CostAcc, [End,Start|PathAcc], CostPath) :-
  edge(Start, End, CostEdge),
  CostPath is CostAcc + CostEdge.

route(Start, End, PathAcc, CostAcc, Path, Cost) :-
  edge(Start, Next, CostEdge),
  \+ memberchk(Next, PathAcc),
  stay(Next, StayTime),
  CostNext is CostAcc + CostEdge + StayTime,
  route(Next, End, [Start|PathAcc], CostNext, Path, Cost).
```

Then, to recover your original interface, we add the entry point :

```
route(Start, End, Route, Cost) :-
  route(Start, End, [], 0, RevRoute, Cost), reverse(RevRoute, Route).
```

Comment: Regarding tail-recursiveness: cf @mat's wrote in an answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17017920/4609915): "[...] *tail call (and hence also tail recursion) optimisation only helps if the predicate is deterministic* [...]"