# order of conditions in antecedent causes stackoverflow

Tags: prolog

As a simple exercise, I wrote my own permutation.

This stack overflows:

```
without(_, [], []).
without(A, [A|T], T).
without(A, [H|T], [H|G]) :- without(A, T, G).

my_permutation([], []).
my_permutation([H|T], P) :- member(H, P), without(H, P, Pp), my_permutation(T, Pp).
```

this works partly, but still stack overflows after giving some of the solution space:

```
without(_, [], []).
without(A, [A|T], T).
without(A, [H|T], [H|G]) :- without(A, T, G).

my_permutation([], []).
my_permutation([H|T], P) :- my_permutation(T, Pp), member(H, P), without(H, P, Pp).
```

this also stack overflows:

```
without(A, [A|T], T).
without(A, [H|T], [H|G]) :- without(A, T, G).

my_permutation([], []).
my_permutation([H|T], P) :- without(H, P, Pp), my_permutation(T, Pp).
```

but this works perfectly:

```
without(A, [A|T], T).
without(A, [H|T], [H|G]) :- without(A, T, G).

my_permutation([], []).
my_permutation([H|T], P) :- my_permutation(T, Pp), without(H, P, Pp).
```

Can anyone please help me understand why?

Comment: `without(_, [], []).` doesn't make sense - no element has been removed.

Comment: Usual reminder: Can use e.g. [trace](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger) to step through the program, to debug it. That will show when and why the infinite loop starts.

Comment: Even without that `without(_, [], [])` it still infinite loops. Also, to me, logically it makes sense, because the empty list with any element removed is still the empty list.

Comment: It's impossible to remove an element from an empty list :-)

Comment: Sure, but this is now a philosophical debate. If I say, I want the empty list without this specific element A, then ok, giving you back the empty list is totally valid logic.

Comment: It's the `[]` in the *2nd* argument which makes it invalid logic. Because: It's impossible to remove an element from an empty list. It's like saying: Take 1 apple away from 0 apples, then how many apples are you left with?

Comment: For my actual question, I looked at the trace, but I don't understand why it doesn't terminate and work with the logic in the opposite order.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this portion:

```
without(H, P, Pp)
```

Both P and Pp are *uninstantiated*, so `without` cheerfully goes into an infinite loop of giving them an increasingly longer length, as per the T and G variables.

Demonstration:

```
?- without(E, L, R).
L = [E|R] ;
L = [_A, E|_B],
R = [_A|_B] ;
L = [_A, _B, E|_C],
R = [_A, _B|_C] ;
L = [_A, _B, _C, E|_D],
R = [_A, _B, _C|_D] ;
... % Increasingly longer
```

The solution is to replace:

```
my_permutation([H|T], P) :- without(H, P, Pp), my_permutation(T, Pp).
```

... so that the list length is restricted, causing termination.

This would suffice (although using `same_length` makes it slower):

```
my_permutation([H|T], P) :-
    same_length([H|T], P),
    without(H, P, Pp),
    my_permutation(T, Pp).
```

Or, more efficiently (using E as a short name for "Element", i.e. element of a list):

```
my_permutation([H|T], [E|P]) :- without(E, [H|T], R), my_permutation(R, P).
```

This clearly ties both arguments of `my_permutation` to be the same length, and passes an instantiated list (`[H|T]`) to `without`.

However, it can still have the problem of passing an uninstantiated list to `without`, if its arguments are swapped:

```
?- my_permutation(L, [1,2,3]).
L = [1, 2, 3] ;
ERROR: Stack limit (1.0Gb) exceeded
```

The advantage of `my_permutation(T, Pp), without(H, P, Pp)` is that *both* arguments of `my_permutation` will have encountered `[], []`, and so have their length known. It is still not perfect, though:

```
?- my_permutation(L, [1,2]).
L = [1, 2] ;
L = [2, 1] ;
% Does not terminate
```

Note that [permutation/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=permutation/2) does not have this problem.

To fix this termination issue, could enforce `same_length` in a more efficient way:

```
my_permutation2(L, P) :-
    same_length(L, P),
    my_permutation2_(L, P).

my_permutation2_([], []).
my_permutation2_([H|T], [E|P]) :-
    without(E, [H|T], R),
    my_permutation2_(R, P).
```

Although, it's faster with those 2 constraint lines flipped in order.

Other permutation methods are shown at https://stackoverflow.com/a/74655536